# Best authentication method for Node.JS RESTful API

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, rest, mobile

I'm suppose to build a web application and a mobile application (for iOS) that share the same database. Currently I'm thiking about having a RESTful API and have both applications (web and iOS) comunicate with the API to access data. My problem is the authentication method that I should use. I've been researching about OAuth2.0 but that's not quite the thing I want because I don't want the user to have to authorize the connection as it happens when you log in somewhere using facebook or google+. I just want to make the login with a username and password and then stay logged in. And this for both the apps (web and iOS). 
I'm using Node.JS and MongoDB to build the API.
I'm trying to do things "the correct way" because this is suppose to be the final project for my masters. 
Can you guys give me some lights in how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use OAuth 2.0 so you have an extensible standard and token-based authentication which enables users to revoke authentication tickets, e.g. if their phone was stolen.

OAuth 2.0 supports various grant types. Those that you from facebook and twitter logins can be summarized as '3-legged oauth', but there's also two grant types for 2-legged OAuth, especially the [resource owner password credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37) (section 4.3 at the end of the page) which will simply exchange username and password for an authentication token. There's no need to implement 3-legged oauth if you don't want to.

I'd suggest to use database-stored tokens over crypto-based self-validating tokens for most use cases. The possibility to revoke individual grants, or all grants of specific client applications is super helpful in practice. It also shortens tokens a lot and reduces the risk of a catastrophic security leak because of a flaw in the implementation. Make sure the token itself is crypto-strong random and use a simple crypto-wrapper around the actual token value to enable cheap identification of (badly) faked tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just have one more question relative to your answer. Isn't keeping database-stored tokens against the principles of RESTful? RESTful is stateless, and in my point of view keeping a database with tokens is not being stateless. Can you clarify this please?

Comment: In a way, authentication is always stateful: you must first authenticate, get a ticket, then perform requests. Whether the server stores the tickets or creates them as self-validating is transparent to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) (no, not the whisky, but the middleware) could be a good thing to test

It allows to choose among many different authentication methods in an easy and transparent way